# KMDF driver building using VisualDDK and Visual studio 2008

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2008, driver, virtualbox, visual-studio-debugging

To build my driver i used VisualDDK in visual studio 2008. In the beginning i start debugging using my computer and virtualBox machine but when i launch the debugging process in visual studio, my virtual machine did not show me the external ip address(normally should show me 192.168.1.102 and 10.0.1.15 in DDKLauncherMonitor but it show me only 10.0.1.15 ).

I stopped using virtual machine and i decide to use real computer. In the second computer i launched DDKLauncherMonitor. And i start debugging from my first computer. I received Udp package in my second machine and also the driver.sys. But when i tried to load the driver from visual studio(First computer) nothing work. Plus this, in the second machine tell me "Windows required digitally signed driver".

There is same one meet this kind of problem and he/she can help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you go into more details when you say "nothing works"? It's possible that your debugger is not set up properly.

This is kind of a pseudo-answer since I'm not overly aware of VisualDDK, but have you considered trying the standard Microsoft debugging tools like WinDbg? If you can acquire Visual Studio 2012 or 2013 Preview, all of the build and debug tools are integrated into the IDE and you will get full support from Microsoft with any problems you may encounter.

As for your second issue, it sounds like you're building a driver and not signing it. Is your target PC 64-bit? What operating system is it? The 64-bit Windows platform requires signed drivers for installation, but this can be disabled.

You can disable the driver signing requirement using the F8 menu when booting your PC; this should fix your "digitally signed driver required" problem, but needs to be done for each reboot.

Another option would be to add a post-build step or some sort of scripted execution of the Microsoft signing tools ([Inf2cat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [SignTool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387764%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) to sign your driver with your company's certificate.